# Jenkins security of Output console faild build

Tags: maven, jenkins, soapui

Iam using Jenkins for testing web services with maven (maven-soapui-plugin) 
    problem: in console out put i have the password of web services !, how i can secure(hide) this users/password ?? or can i limit the acess to console for anonymous people without limit their acess to project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the [Mask Password Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin)

Which allows passwords to be defined in the Jenkins config, or in the job and then these passwords will be encrypted in the job XML and masked in the console log.

Answer (score 0):

The [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) has the option inject passwords at the start of a build. With it you can refer to the passwords with environment variables, and it will also have the effect of hiding all occurences of the injected passwords on the console output.